# Intersection point of two lines in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, intersection

I want to get the intersection point of two polylines in leaflet. 
I have two lines as given below :-

```
var latlng1 = L.latLng(-7.9375, 4.46354);
var latlng2 = L.latLng(-7.96875, 16.11979);
var latlongs1 = [ latlng1, latlng2 ];
var polyline1 = L.polyline(latlongs1, {
    color : 'red'
}).addTo(map);


var latlng3 = L.latLng(-3.5625, 9.31719);
var latlng4 = L.latLng(-12.125, 9.50469);
var latlongs2 = [ latlng3, latlng4 ];
var polyline2 = L.polyline(latlongs2, {
    color : 'blue'
}).addTo(map);
```

I can get the bounds and latlongs of the endpoints of these lines. I can't get the contiguous array of all latlongs of line. Is there any way to get that ?

Comment: I think you need to calculate that on your own. The closest thing to intersection calculation is in `L.LineUtil._getEdgeIntersection`. You can use it as an inspiration. Convert endpoints to pixels, calculate intersection and covert the intersection point back to coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @MichałGrzejszczak I tried the following :  <br>  console.log(polyline1.getBounds().intersects(polyline2.getBounds())); and this is working fine by giving me true or false based on line intersection. True if intersects and false if it does not intersects.  Am I proceeding right to get the intersection point if I check the intersects method in leaflet.js ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to code all the logic, there is a small and easy to use library called [Turf](http://turfjs.org/) that provides several geoprocessing algorithms. You can even use just one of the algorithms mostly independent of the rest of the library.

The [lineIntersects](http://turfjs.org/docs#lineIntersect) module does exactly what you want.

```
var intersection = turf.lineIntersect(polyline1.toGeoJSON(), polyline2.toGeoJSON());
var intersectionCoord = intersection.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
```

Also you can check [the source code of the module](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-line-intersect/index.js) for inspiration.