# Leaflet: Get Intersection Coordinates where 2 Polyline intersects

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on leaflet JS library for adding maps and polylines. I added two polylines using

[image]

I added the following code for adding the points and lines.

```
<script>
L.marker([29.124573, 49.396591], {
    icon: myIcon,
    
    draggable: false,
    
    layer_name: 'new_node_'+a1,
    node_name: this_node_name
  }).addTo(mymap);

L.marker([29.096977, 48.934479], {
    icon: myIcon,
    
    draggable: false,
    
    layer_name: 'new_node_'+a1,
    node_name: this_node_name
  }).addTo(mymap);

lat_lng_array = [
    L.polyline([[29.096977, 48.934479],[29.591371, 49.404144]], { color: 'red' })
    L.polyline([[39.096977, 38.934479],[39.591371, 39.404144]], { color: 'red' })
];
var line = L.layerGroup(lat_lng_array);
line.addTo(mymap);

<script>
```

How can i find the green point lat and lng.

Please help. I try to work with turfjs but failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection point of two lines in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651320/intersection-point-of-two-lines-in-leaflet)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [turfjs](http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineIntersect)

You need to add the turfjs script so import it:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@6.3.0/turf.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use the turf functions. But they need the coords in geojson format (latlng swapped -> lnglat)

```
var intersects = turf.lineIntersect(lat_lng_array[0].toGeoJSON(), lat_lng_array[1].toGeoJSON());

if(intersects.features.length > 0){
  var coords = intersects.features[0].geometry.coordinates
  var latLngPoint = L.latLng(coords[1], coords[1]);
  L.marker(latLngPoint).addTo(mymap)
}
```

PS: Your lines are not intersecting, for testing you can use this:

```
  var lat_lng_array = [
    L.polyline([[0, 0],[10, 10]], { color: 'red' }),
    L.polyline([[0, 10],[10, 0]], { color: 'red' })
  ];

  var group = L.featureGroup(lat_lng_array).addTo(mymap);

  mymap.fitBounds(group.getBounds())
```

Comment: You just copy paste the codes from some other stackoverflow questions. Can you update your answer with my lat lng points so i can get the idea. otherwise this all is useless for me and everyone who will come again.

Comment: I have only lat lng for 2 points and the 2 angles where those lines will be drawn.

Comment: First of all, I DON'T have copied this answer from anywhere, this is the best solution and so there can be other answer with same code. Also I have already posted the code like you need them. The only different is, that I added also a sample with intersected polylines (good for other peoples, because your line sample is bad) but you don't need them for the intersection logic. And you have nowhere described that you only have 2 points with angles ... So I will not provide a answer for something that is not asked. Like you said `"otherwise this all is useless for me and everyone else"`